# Add all duplicates element in php array

Tags: php, arrays

Input array:

```
Array([0] => Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [check] => 1
    [option] => "mk"
)[1] => Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [check] => 3
    [option] => "zz"
)[2] => Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [check] => 5
    [option] => "mk"
))
```

Output array:

```
    Array([0] => Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [check] => 6
    [option] => "mk"
)[1] => Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [check] => 3
    [option] => "zz"
))
```

How to add all values `[check]` for all same `[option]` values and simplifiy an output array by removing already added arrays?

Comment: What exactly is it you are trying to achieve? I'm not sure how you get from the input to the output based on what you said.

Comment: You have input and output, think its clear to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use foreach loop.
Here is the solution.

```
<?php
$arr = [
    ["id" => 1, "check" => 1, "option" => "mk"],
    ["id" => 2, "check" => 3, "option" => "zz"],
    ["id" => 3, "check" => 5, "option" => "mk"]
];

$newArr = [];
foreach($arr as $a) {
    // check if array element is already there based on option key in $newArr. In that case just add check value.
    if(isset($newArr[$a['option']])) {
        $newArr[$a['option']]['check'] += $a['check'];
        continue;
    }
    $newArr[$a['option']] = $a;
}

$newArr = array_values($newArr);
print_r($newArr);
```

Here is the output.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [check] => 6
            [option] => mk
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [check] => 3
            [option] => zz
        )

)
```